# Do Google Colab notebooks share resources?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've been hunting for this for a while now but can't seem to find this info anywhere else?
I'm running multiple Jupiter notebooks on Google Colab.

Do they share resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, each notebook uses a distinct, ephemeral backend for code execution.

You can observe this by, say, creating a file on the local filesystem in one notebook and observing its absence in another. Or, vice versa.

To share files among backends, you can [mount Google Drive](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA) and access shared files there.

Comment: excellent, thanks. I wonder how they pay for the CPU usage :)